# Ubuntu Screencast

Tags: xorg, games, screencast

I want to screencast my minecraft gaming.

I did this firstly with `recordmydesktop` (and `gtk-recordmydesktop`). It works fine, but the file size is too high (564MB for about 5 min).

I also tested Kazam and switched the Codec to H264, AVI and WEBM. The file size is even larger.

Any suggestions for programs or other solutions?

Comment: You have to reduce the size of the recording. try `fmpeg -y -i your_recording.mp4 -s 480x320 -threads 8 -f webm -vcodec libvpx -deinterlace -g 120 -level 216 -profile 0 -qmax 42 -qmin 10 -rc_buf_aggressivity 0.95 -vb 2M -acodec libvorbis -aq 90 -ac 2 your_recording.webm`

Comment: I think this question is more specific.

Answer (score 5):

### [vokoscreen](https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreenNG)

It's free, and you can get it from the Ubuntu Software Center or in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install vokoscreen
```

You can change the filetype easily, the files aren't too large, and it can also record the computers sound.

[image]

Comment: I've changed your answer something. If you do not agree, then you can create your version again: https://askubuntu.com/posts/624544/revisions Use the `rollback` link.

Comment: Good one now!  ;-)

Comment: I just tested this and it worked surprisingly well.  I've done RecordMyDesktop many times and this is nicer in many ways.  It interacted easily with webcam. Can easily indicate a window sided recording area, then move items in and out of recording frame.  I had to run pavucontrol to activate input sound, all else was easy.  I don't see many formats in which to save, maybe I'm missing some libraries. I do get good mkv output. I had grown used to ogv output, don't know if I'd rather have mkv or not.